# jquery moving rows dynamically with .on

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm attempting to move rows between two tables, but I cannot get it to keep the click event bound to it. I'm confused on the selector part on the `.on` event I'm not sure what I'm supposed to be targeting with that.

Basically I can get it to move to one table, and back but then it losses the click property. Not sure why.

I've attached a fiddle(http://jsfiddle.net/Yjqkn/216/) to make the problem clearer. The approve button moves it down, and the waitlist button moves it back, but then it loses all event listeners do I need to rebind them with `.bind` What is the best way to solve this.

I tried : `.on("click","button.remove-participant",function()` didn't work

### Javascript

```
$( ":button" ).on("click",function(){

    if($(this).hasClass('remove-participant')) {
        $(this).removeClass('remove-participant').addClass('add-participant');
        $(this).html('Approve');
        var current_row = $(this).closest('tr').html();

        $('.table_2 > tbody:last').append('<tr>'+current_row+'</tr>');
        $(this).closest('tr').remove();

        $( ".table_2 .add-participant" ).bind( "click", function() {
            $(this).removeClass('add-participant').addClass('remove-participant');
            var current_row = $(this).closest('tr').html();
            $(this).html('Waitlist');

            $('.table_1 > tbody:last').append('<tr>'+current_row+'</tr>');
            $(this).closest('tr').remove();
        });
    }
});
```

HTML

```
<table class="table_1">
  <tr>
    <th>Info Header 1</th><th>Info Header 2</th>
  </tr>
  <tbody>
    <tr><td>Don</td>
      <td><button class="remove-participant" name="">Remove</button></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<table class="table_2">
  <tr>
    <th>Info Header 1</th><th>Info Header 2</th>
  </tr>
  <tbody>
    <tr></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use:

```
$(".table_1").on("click", "button.remove_participant", function() {
    ...
});
```

The general idea with event delegation is that you bind the handler to some element(s) that are static in the DOM and will contain all the dynamically added elements. Then the *selector* argument should specify the more specific dynamic elements that you want to delegate to.

It also doesn't look right that you're binding a `click` handler to `.table_2 .add_participant` within the `button.remove_participant` click handler. Every time you remove a participant, it's going to add another click handler to every `.add_participant` element, so when you click on those elements the handler will run multiple times. You should delegate the handler just once -- the whole point of delegation is that it picks up dynamic changes so you don't need to redo it every time you modify the DOM.

BTW,

```
.removeClass('class1').addClass('class2');
```

can be combined into:

```
toggleClass('class1 class2');
```

Comment: I believe you are correct, all on points thanks i'll try it without the bind.

Answer (score -1):

In my opinion your code is not working is because of your logic. You are here doing this: In table 1, you are removing the class. 
              $(this).removeClass('remove-participant').addClass('add-participant');

When you click on table 2, and do the same thing. But you never go back and add the remove-participant class in table 1. So the click in Table 1 doesnt not work because class is set to 'add-participant' and not changed back.

Comment: His `table_2` code does the opposite changes to the classes, so I think it's essentially doing the right thing.